# How to remove Lombok api from your java code

Tags: java, lombok

I've imported a code from GitHub similar like this:

File 1: `Settings.java`

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;

@Data
@Builder
public class Settings {
    private PDFont font;
    private Integer fontSize;
    //code
}
```

Now this is its usage

File 2:

```
private Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                               .font(DEFAULT_FONT)
                               .fontSize(DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE)
                               .build();
```

Please help me out to convert this both parts in simple code I strictly don't want to use Lombok.

Comment: Why don't you want to use this? It's a nice puglin

Comment: This is only requirement I cant use lombork in my project. I have to generate code all my own

Comment: But you're adding a dependency on a project that uses Lombok, it's not the same as using Lombok yourself. The person who wrote the library could also have written the boilerplate by themselves, it doesn't matter to you (well unless you are plagiarizing the code  you found in Github)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using IntelliJ and you have installed the Lombok plugin you can right click in your editor, go to `Refactor` and then `Delombok`. It works for the most part, but sometimes doesn't. I would not advise you to do that, it would make the code uglier and would force you to have the library checked in as code in your project rather than as a dependency. Just use Lombok, it's a cool plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only two fields in the Settings class, you can create a constructor as below -

```
public class Settings {
  private PDFont font;
  private Integer fontSize;

  public Settings(PDFont font, Integer fontSize) {
    this.font = font;
    this.fontSize = fontSize;
  }

  public PDFont getPDFont() {
    return this.font;
  }

  public Integer getFontSize() {
    return this.fontSize;
  }
}
```

Usage -

```
private Settings settings = new Settings(DEFAULT_FONT, DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE);
```

Comment: If in case i use getters and setters instead of constructor

Comment: thats totally fine

Comment: Perfect  clean answer

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand what u need to do is to [Delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) (by using the plugin or the command line) then copy the generated code (for builders and so on) in your codebase. Regarding `@Data` annotation, I suggest u to user the generate feature of your IDE

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example with unfolded code.

```
public class Settings {
  private PDFont font;
  private Integer fontSize;
  private Settings(Builder builder) {
    this.font = builder.font;
    this.fontSize = builder.fontSize;
  }
  public PDFont getFont() {
    return this.font;
  }
  public void setFont(PDFont font) {
    this.font = font;
  }
  public Integer getFontSize() {
    return this.fontSize;
  }
  public void setFontSize(Integer fontSize) {
    this.fontSize = fontSize;
  }
  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) return true;
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass()) return false;
    Settings other = (Settings)obj;
    return java.util.Objects.equals(this.font, other.font)
        && java.util.Objects.equals(this.fontSize, other.fontSize);
  }
  @Override public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.font, this.fontSize);
  }
  @Override public String toString() {
    return "Settings{font="+this.font+",fontSize="+this.fontSize+"}";
  }
  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }
  public static class Builder {
    PDFont font;
    Integer fontSize;
    private Builder() {
    }
    public Builder font(PDFont font) {
      this.font = font;
      return this;
    }
    public Builder fontSize(Integer fontSize) {
      this.fontSize = fontSize;
      return this;
    }
    public Settings build() {
      return new Settings(this);
    }
  }
  // Code  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your "Delombocked" `Settings` class.

```
public class Settings {
    private PDFont font;
    private Integer fontSize;

    @java.beans.ConstructorProperties( {"font", "fontSize"})
    Settings(PDFont font, Integer fontSize) {
        this.font = font;
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
    }

    public static SettingsBuilder builder() {
        return new SettingsBuilder();
    }

    public PDFont getFont() {
        return this.font;
    }

    public Integer getFontSize() {
        return this.fontSize;
    }

    public void setFont(PDFont font) {
        this.font = font;
    }

    public void setFontSize(Integer fontSize) {
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Settings)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Settings other = (Settings) o;
        if (!other.canEqual((Object) this)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Object this$font = this.getFont();
        final Object other$font = other.getFont();
        if (this$font == null ? other$font != null : !this$font.equals(other$font)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Object this$fontSize = this.getFontSize();
        final Object other$fontSize = other.getFontSize();
        if (this$fontSize == null ? other$fontSize != null : !this$fontSize.equals(other$fontSize)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(final Object other) {
        return other instanceof Settings;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 59;
        int result = 1;
        final Object $font = this.getFont();
        result = result * PRIME + ($font == null ? 43 : $font.hashCode());
        final Object $fontSize = this.getFontSize();
        result = result * PRIME + ($fontSize == null ? 43 : $fontSize.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Main.Settings(font=" + this.getFont() + ", fontSize=" + this.getFontSize() + ")";
    }

    public static class SettingsBuilder {
        private PDFont font;
        private Integer fontSize;

        SettingsBuilder() {
        }

        public Settings.SettingsBuilder font(PDFont font) {
            this.font = font;
            return this;
        }

        public Settings.SettingsBuilder fontSize(Integer fontSize) {
            this.fontSize = fontSize;
            return this;
        }

        public Settings build() {
            return new Settings(font, fontSize);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Main.Settings.SettingsBuilder(font=" + this.font + ", fontSize=" + this.fontSize + ")";
        }
    }
    //code
}
```